# Finding a basis for set of vectors (columns/rows)

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if someone could help me with the following. I have to find a basis for the subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $(1,2,0,3)^T$, $(3,5,1,7)^T$, $ (1,1,1,1)^T$ and $(0,1,-1,2)^T$. Now I know how to find this, but I am a bit confused whether I should let these vectors be the columns of a matrix which I then row reduce, or the rows of such a matrix. I always thought that since these are column vectors, I should let them be the columns (and if they were row vectors, I should let them be the rows). But I now got confused after looking at

http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-a-basis-for-the-span-of-a-given-set-of-vectors/

where the given vectors are row vectors, which are then taken as the columns in a matrix ... So I was hoping someone could help me get this clear when to put the vectors as rows and when to put them as columns in a matrix when finding a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Any vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with dimension $4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ which can also be written $\mathbb{R}_{4 \times 1}$ (so the usual interpretation in most texts I have come across is that the notation $\mathbb{R}^4$ indicates column vectors). So effectively, because of the isomorphism, it doesn't matter if you are given row vectors or column vectors (just make sure the standard bases of these two match!), you can make these vectors the columns of a matrix and then row reduce the matrix to find a basis for the subspace they are spanning.